# How to update stateful widget in Navigation drawer while keeping same class like fragments in Android?

Tags: flutter

I want to update stateful widget of my class while returning same class after getting data from server, from navigation drawer. I am having issue that class loads data only one time and remain the same if I navigate to another item of my navigation drawer. Because the state is created only once.

Here is my code:

```
class CategoryFilter extends StatefulWidget {
 int productIndex;
 String category_name;
 CategoryFilter(this.productIndex, this.category_name)
 {
  print("CategoryFilter");
  print(productIndex);
  print(category_name);
  new _CategoryFilterState(productIndex, category_name);
}

 @override
 _CategoryFilterState createState() => new 
_CategoryFilterState(productIndex, category_name);
}

 class _CategoryFilterState extends State<CategoryFilter> {

 int productIndex;
 List<ResponseDataProducts> productList;
 List data;
 String category_name;

_CategoryFilterState(this.productIndex, this.category_name)
 {
   print("CategoryFilter");
   print(productIndex);
  print(category_name);
}

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();

    Future<String> status = getData(productIndex);

    status.then((onValue){

    if(onValue.toString() == "Success")
    {

      Navigator.pop(context);

    }

  });


  // this.getData();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(

    body: new Container(
        color: Colors.white30,

        child: new ListView.builder(
           itemCount: productList == null ? 0 : productList.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

             return new Container(

               margin: const EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 10.0),
               constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(
                  height: 200.0

               ),
               alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,

               decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                   image: new DecorationImage(image:
                   new NetworkImage
                     ("http://myurl.com/"+productList[index].thumbnail),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)
               ),
               child:new Container(

                 child: new Text(
                   productList[index].name,
                   style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                 ),
                color: Colors.black54,
                 alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
                 height: 35.0,
                 // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),

               ),
             );
            })
    ),
  ) ;
}



  void _onLoading()
  {
    showDialog(context: context,
       barrierDismissible: false,
      child: progress);

    new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2), (){
    // Navigator.pop(context);
   });

  }


   Future<String> getData(int productIndex) async {
   productList = new List<ResponseDataProducts>();


     _onLoading();

   http.Response response = await http.get(
       Uri.encodeFull(CommonMethods.base_url + 'product/$productIndex'),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

print(response.body);

  setState(() {
    var convertDataToJson = JSON.decode(response.body);
    data = convertDataToJson["responseData"];
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
  {

    ResponseDataProducts responseData = new ResponseDataProducts(
        data[i]["id"],
        data[i]["name"], data[i]["description"],
        data[i]["title"], data[i]["thumbnail"]);
    productList.add(responseData);
  }
  //Navigator.pop(context);

});

return "Success";
}
 }
```

Here is how I am calling this categoryFilter class from Navigation Drawer:

```
_getDraserItemWidget(int pos)
 {
  switch(pos)
  {
  case 0:

    return new Home(bar_id);


  case 1:



    return  new CategoryFilter(categoryList[pos-1].id, categoryList[pos-1].name);



  case 2:



  return  new CategoryFilter(categoryList[pos-1].id, categoryList[pos-1].name);


  case 3:


    return  new CategoryFilter(categoryList[pos-1].id, categoryList[pos-1].name);


  case 4:

    return new OpeningTime();


  case 5:

    break;



 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of calling the method to load data within the `initState` method of your class, that you use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget. If you return a new `FutureBuilder` from your Navigation Drawer, that should call your service each time a new one is created, and is generally a better way of performing asynchronous requests anyways.

Here's a very simple example. It doesn't do the drawer very well (or a few other things - there's only so much time to spend on things like this), but it should illustrate the concept.

Note that rather than 'updating the widget' it simply creates a new widget. Because of the way flutter does things, this should be relatively performant, especially because you're not doing it all the time but rather only when the user selects something from the navigation menu.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new TextPage(text: "Home!"),
    );
  }
}

Map<int, int> _nums = Map();

class TextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const TextPage({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new PreferredSize(
        child: new Container(),
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10.0),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(text),
      ),
      drawer: new Builder(
        builder: (context) => Material(
              child: new SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _getDrawerItemWidget(1)));
                      },
                      child: Text("First item"),
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _getDrawerItemWidget(2)));
                      },
                      child: Text("Second item"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getDrawerItemWidget(int i) {
    return new FutureBuilder<String>(
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return new TextPage(text: snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return new TextPage(text: "Loading.");
        }
      },
      future: () async {
        var num = _nums.putIfAbsent(i, () => 0);
        _nums[i] = num + 1;
        String toReturn = "You retrieved number $i for the $num time";
        return await Future.delayed<String>(Duration(seconds: 1), () => toReturn);
      }(),
    );
  }
}
```

You could theoretically do something different with keeping GlobalKey references and using those to call a method on the child widget if it matches the current selection to have it update, but that's generally a bad idea in flutter - best practices encourage you to pass data downwards in the widget tree rather than call functions downwards. If you have to use GlobalKeys, you can generally refactor to do something better.

Comment: Thanks @rmtmckenzie. But this is again not gonna solve my problem of updating widget on second call of same class from Navigation class.

Comment: Sure it does. Since you're making a new future each time you do whatever you do in the navigation drawer, it does the retrieve again and builds a new widget with the result. The new widget will contain the updated data. Plus you get the advantage of being able to define what you want to happen while it's loading (you could theoretically show the old version until then if you want. I'll update my answer with a quick example. Also, the code you've included isn't actually very helpful for someone trying to help you out - you'd be better of including navigation drawer code.